# Is it possible to connect to remote DB while working in localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, git, phpmyadmin

I am working on a project with my developers on localhost. 
We are using git to collaborate but are having issues collaborating the database using git or using a remote db.

Is there any possible way where I can use git or set up a remote server while working with the localhost?

Btw we are using `phpmyadmin`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is. You'll need to whitelist your development servers on the remote server's firewall and allow remote access to the database. If you're using cPanel, there are options there to do so, but you may need to speak to your host as well.

Comment: Okay awesome that sounds good. So p pretty much white list by adding the localhost ip addresss?

Comment: you got it. good luck. if you need help feel free to post more info about your environment. If I helped hook me up with an upvote or a check ;)

Comment: Thanks just went ahead and did it ;)